# Ask Google home to play a mp4 video on my chromecast

Tags: video, dialogflow-es, chromecast, actions-on-google, google-home

What I have :

- A Google Home
- A chromecast on same LAN
- A Personal Video Library accessible by a public API

I want to develop a custom Google Action for my Google Home.

I want to be able to get some random video and play it on my chromecast.

For instance : ***'Ok Google, play random video'***

In DialogFlow, I can easily get the matching intent, find a MP4 video, etc.

But i'm stuck when I want to tell my Google Home to play that video on my Chromecast.

Is there any way to give back to Google Home a rich response (with my mp4 video url) and tell it to play the video on my local chromecast ?

Don't know if this is possible

Thanks !

MC

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to create an Action that can start an application on a Cast device. If you are looking to create video streaming apps that use the existing command set (such as what Netflix does), you need to partner directly with Google.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I think this is a big lack of features ... When we speak to our Google Home we cannot handle the raw message in a server that is hosted in our LAN ?
This [lib](https://github.com/balloob/pychromecast) would work ...

Comment: Google Homes don't run local code. They only send responses from a remote server.

Comment: @NickFelker : It's more like "Google Assistants" don't run local code. 
If you deploy your action in a smartphone, how could you achieve that ?

Comment: This is true. The Actions on Google platform doesn't run local code on any surface, so even a smartphone wouldn't be able to directly do anything on your LAN.